# Add plugins to a maven build by adding a dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to find a way to add technical aspects to a project in a very simple way.

The idea is that every such aspect should be able to add dependencies to the project as well as maven plugins. Each such aspect should be referenced in a very simple way from the user project. Ideally a simple maven dependency but I am open to other good suggestions.

An example would be a user project with the aspects jpa and karaf-command.

- jpa should add the jpa apis and a maven plugin to create persistence.xml from annoations
- karaf-command should add the karaf command api and a maven plugin to create a special Manifest header

I know how to implement the individual plugins. The question is how to add them in the simplest possible way into the user pom.

Does anyone have a good solution how to do this in maven?

Comment: Im not sure what you exactly trying to do. but i think maven Archetype (Maven project templating) assumed to solve such Problems

Comment: The problem with archetype is that it can only cover one aspect. If you want to combine some aspects into one project then you would have to create very many archetypes.

Comment: You could of course implement a plugin which adds dependencies and resolve them...but i wouldn't recommend it cause it would violate the principle of the pom file....The question is what exactly the problem you have you are trying to solve...may be you can give a simple example ?

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/jbonofre/karaf-boot .
Basically we try to do something similar as spring boot. We provide some aspects of your project called starters that you can combine to create your own projects.